# MongoDB C# driver: Setting consecutive item number during insert

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Using mongodbdriver in version 2.10 in a C# project.

I have a document type as follows:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("609720e0fc341e5879c91779"), 
    "number" : "1"
}
```

Currently when creating a new object, I set the number manually:

```
var item = new Item();

item.number = getCollection<Item>().CountDocuments(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument()) + 1;
await getCollection<Item>().InsertOneAsync(item);
```

When executed simultaneously one several machines, this sometimes leads to different documents with the same number, because the count can change between `CountDocuments` and the insert.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("609720e0fc341e5879c91781"), 
    "number" : "2"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("609720e0fc341e5879c91783"), 
    "number" : "2"
}
```

Is there a way, to set this number on insert in an atomic command like so?

```
await getCollection<Item>().InsertOneAsync(item).OnInsertSet(item.number = db.collection<Items>.getCount();
```

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: mongo doesn't offer a built-in way to generate sequential IDs. you have to do it yourself. see [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb) for the technique. if you want a readymade solution, check out this [library](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/Extras-Sequence.html). basically, you need to use `FindOneAndUpdate` to lock and increment a property on a counter document in the db.

Comment: Some related information at a recent Stack Overflow post: [Dealing with race conditions and starvation when generating unique IDs using MongoDB + NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67119727/dealing-with-race-conditions-and-starvation-when-generating-unique-ids-using-mon/67200610#67200610). A relevant blog post:  [Generating Globally Unique Identifiers for Use with MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20MongoDB%20generates%20a,MongoDB%20will%20meet%20application%20requirements.)